# Spring Boot Application,I want to config the location of index.html with applicaiton.properties,but doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a directory that named "jsp" in the following location:

```
resources/public/jsp
```

I want to put `index.html` in jsp folder and this it my `applciaiton.properties` config:

```
spring.resources.static-locations="/jsp/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Use this in application.properties:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/public/jsp/
```